# A bib file for each refsegment

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

Is it possible to use a bib file for each refsegment? I would use a bib file for each refsegment and reset the count of references to each new refsegment.

My code

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel} 

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Section Title A}

\begin{refsegment}

\cite{articleA}\cite{articleC}\cite{articleB}

\printbibliography[segment=1,heading=subbibliography]

\end{refsegment}


\section{Section Title B}

\begin{refsegment}

\cite{articleE}\cite{articleF}\cite{articleD}

\printbibliography[segment=2,heading=subbibliography]

\end{refsegment}

\end{document}
```

**refs.bib**

```
@article{articleA,
    author = {Bruce Wayne},
    title  = {On why batman is stronger than superman},
    journal = {Wayne Enterprises journal},
    year   = {2016},
    keywords = {blablabla},
}
@article{articleB,
author = {Clark Kent},
title  = {On why superman is stronger than batman},
journal = {The daily planet},
year   = {2016},
}
@article{articleC,
    author = {Clark Kent},
    title  = {On why superman is stronger than batman},
    journal = {The daily planet},
    year   = {2016},
}
```

**ref.bib**

```
@article{articleD,
    author = {Bruce Wayne},
    title  = {On why batman is stronger than superman},
    journal = {Wayne Enterprises journal},
    year   = {2016},
    keywords = {blablabla},
}
@article{articleE,
    author = {Clark Kent},
    title  = {On why superman is stronger than batman},
    journal = {The daily planet},
    year   = {2016},
}
@article{articleF,
    author = {Clark Kent},
    title  = {On why superman is stronger than batman},
    journal = {The daily planet},
    year   = {2016},
}
```

O resultado é o seguinte

[image]

I would like to see reference [1  ], [2], [3] in the first section and also [ 1 ], [2], [3] in the second section.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  It sounds like you should be working with refsections instead of refsegments.

Comment: Just replacing the refsegment command with refsection does not work, this way the references in the output do not appear. Need something more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for `refsections` instead of `refsegments`.  This requires compilation with `biber`, rather than `bibtex`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Section Title A}

\begin{refsection}

\cite{articleA}\cite{articleC}\cite{articleB}

\printbibliography[section=1,heading=subbibliography]

\end{refsection}


\section{Section Title B}

\begin{refsection}

\cite{articleE}\cite{articleF}\cite{articleD}

\printbibliography[section=2,heading=subbibliography]

\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

As @moewe points out the syntax

```
\begin{refsection}

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography}

\end{refsection}
```

will also work, since within a `refsection`, the default is to print the bibliography for the current `refsection`.

Comment: I managed to do. The problem was in the TeXstudio editor settings, I decided to change the Default Bibliography Tool to biber. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Since `\printbibliography` automatically defaults to printing the bibliography for the current section. you can drop the `section=1` and `section=2` when you use `\printbibliography` inside `refsection`.

Comment: Is there a style of bibliography that separates the names of 2 or more authors by a comma ","? The style that most resembles what I need is style = nature, but it separates the name of the authors with &, I need to be by comma, according to Brazilian standards.

Comment: I found the solution using style = abnt, thank you very much for the help.

Comment: I understood the suggestion of @moewe , thank you too

Comment: Can I have references separed by chapter/section just in the end of the document, having everthing in a single .bib file?

Comment: @KcFnMi Yes, the syntax `\printbiblography[section=1,...]` can be placed anywhere in the document to output the reference list for the corresponding `refsection`.